# convert text file content into string and pass as a function in F#

Tags: .net, f#, f#-interactive, c#-to-f#, f#-scripting

I want to read a text File and count the number of vowels in it. I want to know how to convert "ParseFile" content in to a string then pass as a variable to countVowels

Obviously, the way I am trying (passing the function) is not working.

```ml
open System.IO
open System


let ParseFile = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\sid\Desktop\AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI\Documents\File3.txt")


\\let countVowels(str : string)

let countVowels (ParseFile) =
    let charList = List.ofSeq str

    let accFunc(As, Es, Is, Os, Us) letter =
        if letter = 'a' then (As+1, Es, Is, Os, Us)
        elif letter = 'e' then (As, Es+1, Is, Os, Us)
        elif letter = 'i' then (As, Es, Is+1, Os, Us)
        elif letter = 'o' then (As, Es, Is, Os+1, Us)
        elif letter = 'u' then (As, Es, Is, Os, Us+1)
        else                   (As, Es, Is, Os, Us)

    List.fold accFunc (0, 0, 0, 0, 0) charList
```

Comment: Parameter passing is programming 101. Voting to close as this sort of thing is covered extensively in virtually _any_ F# literature. You can start with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few issues with your code:

The line:

```
let ParseFile = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\sid\Desktop\AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI\Documents\File3.txt")
```

Either this line should be:

```
let ParseFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sid\Desktop\AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI\Documents\File3.txt")
```

or it should be

```
let ParseFile = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\sid\\Desktop\\AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI\\Documents\\File3.txt")
```

But either way it's not right as it currently stands because either you either need to escape the string with an "@" or you need to escape the backslashes by doubling them.

Try fixing that one--as I say there are other issues but try fixing that one first and then see if you can figure out the other ones for yourself.  As Daniel said you should be able to get this working by yourself with a little work.

EDIT:

Oh what the heck; I've benefitted from the largesse of more experienced developers over the years so I can help a bit more than that.

Change this:

```
let countVowels (ParseFile) =
```

to this:

```
let countVowels str =
```

Then add this to the end of your file:

```
countVowels ParseFile
```

And, again, as Daniel said, this is pretty basic so if you're just starting, take some time to read the reference he pointed you at and try to understand what you're reading.  If you can't master this, you've got no future in software development :-)

Comment: Thank you for your corrections and suggestions. Its very helpful. I am supposed to learn F# from scartch and do a web app in two weeks. Yes, I am starting .NET and functional paradigm. That's a bit demotivating so thank you for your tough remarks got me charged up to work more :)

Comment: I'm not meaning to be tough Siddhartha; I'm saying (as I think Daniel is) that passing a parameter to a function is a pretty basic concept in _any_ programming language. If you've done C# before, the syntax is a little different but the concept is the same. From your example code it's hard to tell if you've even grasped the concept.

Comment: I meant tough in a comic sense :) You are right the concept is not clear to me. I am thinking of it entirely differently just because its functional. Thats probably the wrong approach. I had difficulty understanding prolog too because I am not comfortable with scripting language.

Comment: Concept as in that of arguments or parameter passing in F#. I understand very well how it works in Object Oriented.

Comment: Can I use either of your code to read a ".txt" file present in the given path? I don't get "But either way it's not right as it currently stands because either you either need to escape the string with an "@" or you need to escape the backslashes by doubling them". How does the @ or // change affect the purpose of reading the text file as a string?

Comment: If you don't modify the string constant to either double up the forward slash or proceed it with a "@" the F# compiler won't parse the string literal correctly and therefore won't find the file correctly.  This is no different than C#; the same issue would be present in C#.